# Can I sync arbitrary google drive directories?

Tags: sync, google-drive

Is there some way that I can keep certain directories in google drive synchronized with various local dirs? I've looked at a couple apps (SyncDrive, grive), but it looks like they just sync my entire google drive to a single location. I only want certain directories to sync, and I have multiple google accounts: a personal account, and a google apps managed account for work.